# Is there anyway that I can initialize members on conditional basis without pre processor directives?

Tags: c, struct

I have an array of structures. During initialization, I need to initialize on conditional basis. say

```
struct struct_name[arraySize] = { {1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'},
#if condition
    {3, 'c'}
#else
    {4, 'd'}
#endif
    };
```

In the above code, I controlled initialization using pre processor directives. Is there anyway I can do this conditional compilation without using pre processor directives?

Comment: I do not have the "conditon" macro defined. and i cannot do it in my project. and so this question. Please help

Comment: Can you give an example of what the condition might be?

Comment: Why the downvote? Regarding the average C question, I feel this is a good question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with the ternary operator, like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struc {
    int number;
    char letter;
    };

int main()
{
    int condition = 1;
    struct struc array[] = {{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {condition ? 3:4, condition ? 'c':'d'}};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the question states that `condition` is a macro, which is undefined.

Comment: With modern C++ `array` could even go to read only memory if declared const and if `condition` is a constexpr (and compile time computable) which it must be if used in a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @PeterSchneider But this is a C question?!

Comment: @unwind Yes of course: "With modern C++"... It just came to mind.

Comment: @unwind the question does not mention macro, indeed OP commented *"I do not have the "conditon" macro defined. and i cannot do it in my project."*

Comment: @WeatherVane Fine, the OP commented his/her question to add this information. Big difference?

Comment: @unwind sorry I don't know what you mean. The question showed how using pre processor directives works, but asked how to do it without, and that would include macros? My answer shows how to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you are under C99 you can use compound literals:

```
struct x a[] = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'},condition?(struct x){3,'c'}:(struct x){4,'d'}};
```

Another (obfuscated) way:

```
struct x a[] = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'},(struct x[]){{3,'c'},{4,'d'}}[!!condition]};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't have a C compiler to use at the moment, I can't check if this works in C, but it works in C++. It uses the ternary `?` operator:

```
int a = 1;

char arr[3] = { 'b', (a == 1 ? 'c' : 'd'), 0 };

int main()
{
    printf(arr);
    printf("\n");
}
```